# product of diagonal matrix and positive definite hermitian matrix diagonnaly dominant

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $K_p$ be a positive definite hermitian matrix diagonnaly dominant (fyi: it is a stiffness matrix and each element is real),
$K_n$ another positive definite hermitian matrix diagonnaly dominant (fyi: it is a stiffness matrix and each element is real),
and $L$ a diagonal matrix. Each element of $L$ is a positive real number included in $[0,1]$.

Is the product $LK^{-1}_nK_p$ positive definite ? positive semi-definite ? Neither of them ? If so, what are the conditions on $L$ to have $LK^{-1}_nK_p$ positive definite or positive semi-definite.

According to me, $LK^{-1}_nK_p$ is not positive definite or positive semi-definite as the matrices cannot commute (am I right ?). For the rest, I really reach stalemate.

Thank you in advance for your help.
EM

Comment: I would be more worried that $LK_n^{-1}K_p$ is not symmetric anymore. On the other hand, a product of positive definite matrices has positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you very much for this first answer that helps a lot. However, I am not sure that I completely understood: Was I right to say that the product is not positive definite or positive semi-definite ?

Comment: What is your definition then? Usually it includes symmetry (necessary in the complex case).

Comment: I found here https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v15/cjm1963v15.0313-0317.pdf something that helped me. I think that my question is not as well formulated as I thought. Thank you for your time.